# Access to Microsoft CRM Dynamics 365 from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I need access to CRM Dynamics 365 i use below code to access its worked fine with "ADFS (IFD) Authentication", but with CRM Online "Dynamics 365 https://OrgName.api.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"

getting this Error:

**An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.**

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.Issue(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateInternal(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateWithOrgIdForACS(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials, Uri identifier)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateOnlineFederationInternal(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.Authenticate(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceConfiguration.Authenticate(AuthenticationCredentials authenticationCredentials)
```

This my code:

```
public static IOrganizationService GetService()
{

    try
    {
        OrganizationServiceProxy _serviceProxy;

        string userName = "";
        string password = "";
        string domain = "";
        Uri serviceUri;


        serviceUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
        userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"];


        IServiceManagement<IOrganizationService> orgServiceManagement = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateManagement<IOrganizationService>(serviceUri);

        if (orgServiceManagement.AuthenticationType == AuthenticationProviderType.Federation)
        {
            // ADFS (IFD) Authentication
            ClientCredentials clientCred = new ClientCredentials();
            clientCred.UserName.UserName = userName;
            clientCred.UserName.Password = password;
            _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, clientCred);
        }
        else if (orgServiceManagement.AuthenticationType == AuthenticationProviderType.OnlineFederation)
        {
            // Online authentication
            AuthenticationCredentials authCredentials = new AuthenticationCredentials();

            authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
            authCredentials.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

            // Error getting here
            AuthenticationCredentials tokenCredentials = orgServiceManagement.Authenticate(authCredentials); 


            _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(orgServiceManagement, tokenCredentials.SecurityTokenResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            // On-Premise, non-IFD authentication
            ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
            credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            _serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, credentials, null);
        }

        _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

    return (IOrganizationService)_serviceProxy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These may be the reasons for that:

1. Microsoft has deprecated Azure Access Control Service (ACS)
2. Microsoft removed Microsoft.Xrm.Client from the CRM 2016 (8.x) SDK client because it was not compliant with the OAuth changes, and replaced it with Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.
3. Microsoft modified their SDK authentication code by removing all references to ACS. Effective from versions Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Update 1 (v8.1.1) and Microsoft Dynamics 365 (v8.2). They also removed Live ID support and ACS dependencies on the server-side.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2017/02/01/dynamics-365-sdk-backwards-compatibility/

The proposed way to go is to use the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector. Please see the example below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!-- Online using Office 365 -->
    <!-- <add name="Server=CRM Online, organization=contoso, user=someone"
         connectionString="Url=https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com; Username=someone@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; Password=password; authtype=Office365"/> -->

    <!-- On-premises with provided user credentials -->
    <!-- <add name="Server=myserver, organization=AdventureWorksCycle, user=administrator"
         connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle; Domain=mydomain; Username=administrator; Password=password; authtype=AD"/> -->

    <!-- On-premises using Windows integrated security -->
    <!-- <add name="Server=myserver, organization=AdventureWorksCycle"
         connectionString="Url=http://myserver/AdventureWorksCycle; authtype=AD"/> -->

    <!-- On-Premises (IFD) with claims -->
    <!--<add name="Server=litware.com, organization=contoso, user=someone@litware.com"
         connectionString="Url=https://contoso.litware.com; Username=someone@litware.com; Password=password; authtype=IFD"/>-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
      <source name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient" switchName="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
          <add name="fileListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl" switchName="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
          <add name="fileListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="CrmSvcUtil" switchName="CrmSvcUtil" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
          <add name="fileListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>

      <!--Possible values for switches: Off, Error, Warning, Information, Verbose
                        Verbose:      includes Error, Warning, Info, Trace levels
                        Information:  includes Error, Warning, Info levels
                        Warning:      includes Error, Warning levels
                        Error:        includes Error level-->

      <add name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.CrmConnectControl" value="Off"/>
      <add name="Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient" value="Error"/>
      <add name="CrmSvcUtil" value="Off"/>
    </switches>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="fileListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="CrmSvcUtil.log"/>
    </sharedListeners>

  </system.diagnostics>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Deployment" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ServiceBus" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

This is the C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel;

// These namespaces are found in the Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll assembly
// located in the SDK\bin folder of the SDK download.
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;

// These namespaces are found in the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll assembly
// located in the SDK\bin folder of the SDK download.
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

// These namespaces are found in the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll assembly
// located in the SDK\bin folder of the SDK download.
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This sample uses the CrmConnection class found in the Microsoft.Xrm.Client
    /// namespace to connect to and authenticate with the organization web service.
    /// 
    /// Next, the sample demonstrates how to do basic entity operations like create,
    /// retrieve, update, and delete.</summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// At run-time, you will be given the option to delete all the database
    /// records created by this program.
    /// 
    /// No helper code from CrmServiceHelpers.cs is used in this sample.</remarks>
    /// <see cref="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810.aspx"/>
    public class SimplifiedConnection
    {
        #region Class Level Members

        private Guid _accountId;
        private IOrganizationService _orgService;

        #endregion Class Level Members

         /// <summary>
        /// The Run() method first connects to the Organization service. Afterwards,
        /// basic create, retrieve, update, and delete entity operations are performed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString">Provides service connection information.</param>
        /// <param name="promptforDelete">When True, the user will be prompted to delete all
        /// created entities.</param>
        public void Run(String connectionString, bool promptforDelete)
        {
            try
            {
                // Connect to the CRM web service using a connection string.
                CrmServiceClient conn = new Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

                // Cast the proxy client to the IOrganizationService interface.
                _orgService = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

                //Create any entity records this sample requires.
                CreateRequiredRecords();

                // Obtain information about the logged on user from the web service.
                Guid userid = ((WhoAmIResponse)_orgService.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest())).UserId;
                SystemUser systemUser = (SystemUser)_orgService.Retrieve("systemuser", userid,
                    new ColumnSet(new string[] { "firstname", "lastname" }));
                Console.WriteLine("Logged on user is {0} {1}.", systemUser.FirstName, systemUser.LastName);

                // Retrieve the version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
                RetrieveVersionRequest versionRequest = new RetrieveVersionRequest();
                RetrieveVersionResponse versionResponse =
                    (RetrieveVersionResponse)_orgService.Execute(versionRequest);
                Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Dynamics CRM version {0}.", versionResponse.Version);

                // Instantiate an account object. Note the use of option set enumerations defined in OptionSets.cs.
                // Refer to the Entity Metadata topic in the SDK documentation to determine which attributes must
                // be set for each entity.
                Account account = new Account { Name = "Fourth Coffee" };
                account.AccountCategoryCode = new OptionSetValue((int)AccountAccountCategoryCode.PreferredCustomer);
                account.CustomerTypeCode = new OptionSetValue((int)AccountCustomerTypeCode.Investor);

                // Create an account record named Fourth Coffee.
                _accountId = _orgService.Create(account);

                Console.Write("{0} {1} created, ", account.LogicalName, account.Name);

                // Retrieve the several attributes from the new account.
                ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet(
                    new String[] { "name", "address1_postalcode", "lastusedincampaign" });

                Account retrievedAccount = (Account)_orgService.Retrieve("account", _accountId, cols);
                Console.Write("retrieved, ");

                // Update the postal code attribute.
                retrievedAccount.Address1_PostalCode = "98052";

                // The address 2 postal code was set accidentally, so set it to null.
                retrievedAccount.Address2_PostalCode = null;

                // Shows use of a Money value.
                retrievedAccount.Revenue = new Money(5000000);

                // Shows use of a Boolean value.
                retrievedAccount.CreditOnHold = false;

                // Update the account record.
                _orgService.Update(retrievedAccount);
                Console.WriteLine("and updated.");

                // Delete any entity records this sample created.
                DeleteRequiredRecords(promptforDelete);
            }

            // Catch any service fault exceptions that Microsoft Dynamics CRM throws.
            catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>)
            {
                // You can handle an exception here or pass it back to the calling method.
                throw;
            }
        }

        #region Public Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates any entity records this sample requires.
        /// </summary>
        public void CreateRequiredRecords()
        {
            // For this sample, all required entities are created in the Run() method.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes any entity records that were created for this sample.
        /// <param name="prompt">Indicates whether to prompt the user 
        /// to delete the records created in this sample.</param>
        /// </summary>
        public void DeleteRequiredRecords(bool prompt)
        {
            bool deleteRecords = true;

            if (prompt)
            {
                Console.Write("\nDo you want these entity records deleted? (y/n) [y]: ");
                String answer = Console.ReadLine();

                deleteRecords = (answer.StartsWith("y") || answer.StartsWith("Y") || answer == String.Empty);
            }

            if (deleteRecords)
            {
                _orgService.Delete(Account.EntityLogicalName, _accountId);
                Console.WriteLine("Entity records have been deleted.");
            }
        }

        #endregion Public Methods

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets web service connection information from the app.config file.
        /// If there is more than one available, the user is prompted to select
        /// the desired connection configuration by name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A string containing web service connection configuration information.</returns>
        private static String GetServiceConfiguration()
        {
            // Get available connection strings from app.config.
            int count = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Count;

            // Create a filter list of connection strings so that we have a list of valid
            // connection strings for Microsoft Dynamics CRM only.
            List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> filteredConnectionStrings = 
                new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>>();

            for (int a = 0; a < count; a++)
            {
                if (isValidConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[a].ConnectionString))
                    filteredConnectionStrings.Add
                        (new KeyValuePair<string, string>
                            (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[a].Name,
                            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[a].ConnectionString));
            }

            // No valid connections strings found. Write out and error message.
            if (filteredConnectionStrings.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An app.config file containing at least one valid Microsoft Dynamics CRM " +
                    "connection string configuration must exist in the run-time folder.");
                Console.WriteLine("\nThere are several commented out example connection strings in " +
                    "the provided app.config file. Uncomment one of them and modify the string according " +
                    "to your Microsoft Dynamics CRM installation. Then re-run the sample.");
                return null;
            }

            // If one valid connection string is found, use that.
            if (filteredConnectionStrings.Count == 1)
            {
                return filteredConnectionStrings[0].Value;
            }

            // If more than one valid connection string is found, let the user decide which to use.
            if (filteredConnectionStrings.Count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The following connections are available:");
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");

                for (int i = 0; i < filteredConnectionStrings.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n({0}) {1}\t",
                    i + 1, filteredConnectionStrings[i].Key);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                Console.Write("\nType the number of the connection to use (1-{0}) [{0}] : ", 
                    filteredConnectionStrings.Count);
                String input = Console.ReadLine();
                int configNumber;
                if (input == String.Empty) input = filteredConnectionStrings.Count.ToString();
                if (!Int32.TryParse(input, out configNumber) || configNumber > count || 
                    configNumber == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Option not valid.");
                    return null;
                }

                return filteredConnectionStrings[configNumber - 1].Value;

            }
            return null;

        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Verifies if a connection string is valid for Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True for a valid string, otherwise False.</returns>
        private static Boolean isValidConnectionString(String connectionString)
        {
            // At a minimum, a connection string must contain one of these arguments.
            if (connectionString.Contains("Url=") ||
                connectionString.Contains("Server=") ||
                connectionString.Contains("ServiceUri="))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        #endregion Private Methods

        #region Main method

        /// <summary>
        /// Standard Main() method used by most SDK samples.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        static public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // Obtain connection configuration information for the Microsoft Dynamics
                // CRM organization web service.
                String connectionString = GetServiceConfiguration();

                if (connectionString != null)
                {
                    SimplifiedConnection app = new SimplifiedConnection();
                    app.Run(connectionString, true);
                }
            }

            catch (FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", ex.Detail.Timestamp);
                Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", ex.Detail.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Detail.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", ex.Detail.TraceText);
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                    null == ex.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
            }
            catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                    null == ex.InnerException.Message ? "No Inner Fault" : ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The application terminated with an error.");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                // Display the details of the inner exception.
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);

                    FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault> fe = ex.InnerException
                        as FaultException<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault>;
                    if (fe != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: {0}", fe.Detail.Timestamp);
                        Console.WriteLine("Code: {0}", fe.Detail.ErrorCode);
                        Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", fe.Detail.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine("Trace: {0}", fe.Detail.TraceText);
                        Console.WriteLine("Inner Fault: {0}",
                            null == fe.Detail.InnerFault ? "No Inner Fault" : "Has Inner Fault");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Additional exceptions to catch: SecurityTokenValidationException, ExpiredSecurityTokenException,
            // SecurityAccessDeniedException, MessageSecurityException, and SecurityNegotiationException.

            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        #endregion Main method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the fix from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309305.aspx) article:

*To fix this, you can try deleting the device registration folder named LiveDeviceID in your profile folder C:\Users\. Then, try to connect again.*

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i deleted LiveDeviceID folder but still throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

its Solved by using this code in this [Connect to CRM Online or On-premise](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/12/09/connect-to-crm-online-or-on-premise-using-c/)